# wix execute customaction like command line without calling rollback on failure

Tags: windows, wix, installation

Is there a way to run a custom action like command lince in wix and make installation continue without triggering rollback?

Comment: Have you tried setting the "Return" property of your CustomAction element to "Ignore"?

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks.  How about adding showing of dialog box? So that users will be notified that the custom action did not complete successfully.

Comment: No, that's not available, unless you write a custom action that runs the exe and reports back in a non-failure way. Consider custom actions to be an implementation detail that the user shouldn't have to know about, so telling them it failed isn't helpful.